# My system generates 900 000 lines of error log in the span of one minute and then has to be rebooted to work

Tags: wireless, games, log, syslog

My system does something weird. If I do something that my computer doesn't like then it logs 900 000 lines of error logs and stops working. Last time this happened I had just started a game of DotA and everything stopped working. After I checked the logs I found this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j-pU8Ng4-vBXp649RdWSQC7KWcQ2EaYI/view?usp=sharing

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Some logs look like this:

```
    Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.786630] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787006] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787008] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787010] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000034 | NMI_INTERRUPT_WDG           
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787011] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B022F0 | trm_hw_status0
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787012] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787013] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004882DA | branchlink2
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787013] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0047932A | interruptlink1
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787014] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000DB5E | interruptlink2
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001AA62 | data1
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000003FF | data2
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787017] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0002C3FF | data3
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787018] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FC1561C | beacon time
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787019] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1CB2A9EC | tsf low
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000039 | tsf hi
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787020] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787021] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD837E1EA | time gp2
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787022] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787023] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000002E | uCode version major
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x6BF1DF06 | uCode version minor
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787025] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000312 | hw version
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787026] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89008 | board version
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787027] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A81001C | hcmd
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787028] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00023882 | isr0
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787028] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00440000 | isr1
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787029] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08201812 | isr2
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787030] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x40437DC3 | isr3
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0A80001C | last cmd Id
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001AA62 | wait_event
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787034] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787035] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787036] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787037] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000001D | lmpm_pmg_sel
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x08081425 | timestamp
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00002888 | flow_handler
Sep  1 17:07:35 ivand-main kernel: [25467.787181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:

    end
```

And other errors look like this:

```
    Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918030] wlo1:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918053] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 44765 at net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:17 drv_sta_state+0x2c5/0x480 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918054] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg psnap llc bnep ip6table_filter ip6table_nat ip6table_mangle ip6_tables iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c iptable_mangle bpfilter binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) nvidia(PO) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_sof intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi kvm_intel snd_soc_core snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm snd_hda_codec_generic snd_compress ac97_bus ledtrig_audio snd_pcm_dmaengine wl(PO) snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg mei_hdcp crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hwdep snd_pcm iwlmvm intel_rapl_msr mac80211 snd_seq_midi uvcvideo snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel libarc4 snd_rawmidi btusb videobuf2_vmalloc crypto_simd
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918087]  videobuf2_memops btrtl cryptd videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq i915 btbcm glue_helper videobuf2_common joydev btintel intel_cstate snd_seq_device videodev iwlwifi snd_timer intel_rapl_perf bluetooth input_leds asus_nb_wmi mc drm_kms_helper serio_raw asus_wmi snd ipmi_devintf cfg80211 sparse_keymap i2c_algo_bit ecdh_generic ipmi_msghandler ecc processor_thermal_device wmi_bmof fb_sys_fops hid_multitouch mei_me mxm_wmi soundcore syscopyarea intel_rapl_common sysfillrect mei int340x_thermal_zone sysimgblt intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal mac_hid int3400_thermal asus_wireless acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul i2c_i801 intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss r8169 idma64 ahci i2c_hid realtek libahci virt_dma hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake pinctrl_intel
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918102] CPU: 1 PID: 44765 Comm: kworker/1:0 Tainted: P        W  O      5.4.0-42-lowlatency #46-Ubuntu
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918102] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. TUF GAMING FX504GM_FX80GM/FX504GM, BIOS FX504GM.307 04/30/2019
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918112] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918123] RIP: 0010:drv_sta_state+0x2c5/0x480 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918124] Code: f1 45 31 ed e9 eb fd ff ff 48 8b 83 78 04 00 00 48 8d b3 98 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 c8 f8 b7 c0 48 85 c0 48 0f 45 f0 e8 e6 63 da f1 <0f> 0b 41 bd fb ff ff ff e9 c2 fd ff ff 65 8b 05 37 3a 51 3f 89 c0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918125] RSP: 0018:ffffba55c6067860 EFLAGS: 00010286
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918126] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff98fc6505e8c0 RCX: 0000000000000006
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918126] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000082 RDI: ffff98fc6d8578c0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918127] RBP: ffffba55c6067898 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000062454
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918128] R10: 0000000000012f48 R11: 0000000000000004 R12: ffff98fc615207a0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918128] R13: ffff98fc615207a0 R14: 0000000000000004 R15: ffff98fc61520d68
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918129] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff98fc6d840000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918130] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918130] CR2: 00005563538e8ab8 CR3: 000000028700a003 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918131] Call Trace:
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918142]  sta_info_move_state+0x26d/0x370 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918152]  __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x31/0x180 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918166]  __sta_info_flush+0x138/0x190 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918183]  ieee80211_set_disassoc+0xbf/0x620 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918197]  ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x104/0x4e0 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918211]  ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918226]  cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xb6/0x210 [cfg80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918239]  cfg80211_disconnect+0x9f/0x210 [cfg80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918249]  __cfg80211_leave+0x133/0x1b0 [cfg80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918260]  cfg80211_leave+0x2c/0x40 [cfg80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918272]  cfg80211_netdev_notifier_call+0x1b2/0x5c0 [cfg80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918274]  ? wake_up_klogd.part.0+0x3b/0x50
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918275]  ? vprintk_emit+0x1ad/0x2b0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918277]  ? vprintk_default+0x29/0x50
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918278]  ? vprintk_func+0x4d/0xde
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918291]  ? ieee80211_reconfig+0xd3/0x1310 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918293]  ? rtnl_is_locked+0x15/0x20
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918294]  ? inetdev_event+0x47/0x560
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918297]  ? skb_dequeue+0x5a/0x70
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918299]  notifier_call_chain+0x55/0x80
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918300]  raw_notifier_call_chain+0x16/0x20
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918302]  call_netdevice_notifiers_info+0x2e/0x60
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918303]  __dev_close_many+0x5e/0x110
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918307]  dev_close_many+0x91/0x150
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918310]  dev_close.part.0+0x4a/0x70
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918314]  dev_close+0x18/0x20
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918326]  cfg80211_shutdown_all_interfaces+0x77/0xd0 [cfg80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918345]  ieee80211_handle_reconfig_failure+0x9d/0xb0 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918365]  ieee80211_reconfig+0xa0/0x1310 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918379]  ieee80211_restart_work+0xc3/0xf0 [mac80211]
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918381]  process_one_work+0x1e2/0x3d0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918384]  worker_thread+0x4a/0x3d0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918386]  kthread+0x104/0x140
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918387]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918388]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918390]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918392] ---[ end trace 90c9f893da445c3a ]---
Sep  1 17:07:42 ivand-main kernel: [25474.918412] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

end

PLUS some other errors in between those two.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the question as needed. I hope it helps.

Comment: Google "wlo1:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4".

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I tried to recreate it, but the only successful recreation happens when I start a search for a DotA game. My bios is up to date now.
The strange thing is that it happens on ethernet as well as on wifi, so that leads me to believe it is not a wifi issue and instead is something more central. I will recreate it tomorrow using ethernet and I will post the logs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a hardware one. My wifi adapter failed for some reason and after I changed it, it resolved itself. Ubuntu doesn't handle hardware malfunctions without losing it apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The default logging system on my 12.04 is rsyslog. It supports and option to remove duplicates. This might help reduce the volume.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26337/suppress-duplicate-messages-in-rsyslog

On systems with excess log rates we install a tool called logrotate.
https://www.tecmint.com/install-logrotate-to-manage-log-rotation-in-linux/
You can configure the rotation rate by date/time and by size. It will also compress or remove older logs to save space. This could be another workaround.

Ultimately the application generating the log messages needs to be fixed.